# Initialize a member object in the constructor's body

Tags: c++

This example code gives an error because there is no appropriate default constructor available:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int x)
    {

    }

};

class B
{
public:
    B(int someValue)
    {
        /* Do a calculation with someValue */
        /* Initialize A member with the calculated value */
    }

private:
    A member;

};
```

I know I can call an specific constructor using the initialization list:

```
B(int someValue)
        : member(someValue)
```

But the problem is that I don't want to create the member object with "someValue", I want to calculate a variable with "someValue" first and then use the result to create the member object.

I know that I can put a formula in the initialization list, but in my real code that is not enough because I need to create some other objects, do some if statements, etc...

How can I do that? I tried just inserting an empty default constructor in class A, and then in B's constructor

```
member = A(calculatedValue);
```

But this already created the member object with the default constructor, so the destructor was being called and that made errors because was trying to delete some memory that was never initialized.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `B(int someValue): A{Calculate_Value()} `

Comment: If multiple statements are required then why not just define a function that returns the base object to the initializer?